# Number of ways to get from top left corner to bottom right corner in MxN grid while moving only down or right. What is time and space complexity?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, space-complexity

**The problem**: find a number of possible ways from top left corner to bottom right corner in MxN grid while you can only move down or right.

Here are two algorithms I have written. Results look ok but I can't figure out time and space complexity, I have some guesses about what the complexities might be but I can't prove them in a "proper" way.

---

**Naive algorithm:**

```
    function gridTravel(m, n) {
      if(m<1 || n<1) return 0;
      if (m === 1 || n === 1) return 1;
      return gridTravel(m-1, n) + gridTravel(m, n-1);
    };
    console.log(gridTravel(10,10));
```

**My guesses**:

- Space complexity - O(n+m)? The longest possible call stack seems to scale "linearly" so assuming some approximation it would be O(n+m) but I can't really prove it or disprove it.
- Time complexity is exponential because each position can create 2 new positions - O(2^n) or O(2^n+m), not sure which is more fitting.

```
                   m:n
        m-1:n                m:n-1
    m-2:n  m-1:n-1     m-1:n-1   m:n-2
```

But again, I don't feel confident with this explanation because it isn't simmetrical tree it just looks like it at the beginning.

---

**Naive algo + memoization:**

```
    seenGrids = {};
    const gridTravel = (m, n) => {
      if(m<1 || n<1) return 0;
      if (m === 1 || n === 1) return 1;
      if (`${m}:${n}` in seenGrids || `${n}:${m}` in seenGrids) {
        return seenGrids[`${m}:${n}`] || seenGrids[`${n}:${m}`];
      }
      seenGrids[`${m}:${n}`] = gridTravel(m-1, n) + gridTravel(m, n-1);
      return seenGrids[`${m}:${n}`];
    };
```

**My guesses:**

- Space - O(n*m)? Call stack still seems to be linear but now we have this growing object `seenGrids` which based on my intuition should scale kind of in a quadratic way? I have no idea how to prove it or disprove it, when I ran `console.log(Object.keys(seenGrids).length)` for `200x200` grid I got `19900` which isn't either `m*n` or `m+n` so is it  linear or quadratic?
- Time - O(n*m)? - this is the hardest for me to wrap my head around. It shouldn't be exponential anymore because a lot of subtrees are skipped thanks to saved answers but I have no idea how to derive time complexity in a "proper" way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First Algorithm:**

For the time complexity, the easiest prove is your method! I mean the computation tree of the recursive function. As you can see, there is a binary tree for the expansion, and the maximum length of the tree is `min(n,m)`. Hence, the time complexity is in `O(2^(min(m,n)))`.

For the space complexity, as you have noted, the computation of the stack will be done in a depth-first manner. Hence, as the maximum branch of each node is 2 and the maximum length of the tree is `min(m,n)` (as discussed in the previous paragraph), the space complexity will be `2 min(m,n)`.

**Second Algorithm**:

As the maximum different combination of inputs is `m * n` ([1, 2, ..., m] and [1, 2, ..., n] for the first and the second inputs of the function, respectively), and the worst case of the stack call is in `O(min(m, n))`, the space complexity is in `O(m * n)`, which is the size of the memory array.

For the time complexity, we can ensure that each element of the array will be computed once (as it's memorized). Hence, independent of the complexity of recursive callbacks, and due to depth-first computing of the recursion (from bottom-up), the time complexity of the second algorithm is in `O(m * n)`.

Comment: are you sure that  size of the stack will be exponential in navie algo? The way I visualize it, it goes along left branch of the tree and once it gets to the leaf, leaf returns value immediately so it is popped from the stack then go back to the parent of that leaf and go to the right child and repeat. So from my pov we don't actually create a call stack that keeps all of the possible calls because it pops a lot on the way.

By leafs I mean "nodes" that don't branch into other calls but instead return a value immediately

Comment: @hdw3 you're definitely right. I made a mistake! It's updated.